# change button color react native

Tags: reactjs, native

I want to simply change the color of the button, but i can't. I tried to change directly in the button, and pass a style to it. But neither of them worked.
Here's my very simple code.

```
 export default class Dots extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Image style={styles.container}  source={require('./background3.png')}>
      <Button title='play' style = {{color:'red'}}/>
      </Image>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex:1,
    backgroundColor:'transparent',
    resizeMode:'cover',
    justifyContent:'center',
    alignItems:'center',
    width:null,
    height:null
  },

  button:{
  backgroundColor:'#ff5c5c',
  }

});
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The react `Button` component renders the native button on each platform it uses. Because of this, it does not respond to the `style` prop. It has its own set of props.

The correct way to use it would have been

`<Button color="#ff5c5c" title="I'm a button!" />`

You can see the documentation at https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/button.html

Now, say you do want to make super customizable button, for that you'll have to use views and touchable opacity. Something along the lines of this.

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={...}>
  {... button markup}
</TouchableOpacity>
```

You'll wrap that up in your own button component and use it.

Comment: color='#ff5c5c' change background color in android. How can I change text color and font size?

Comment: There's a problem here.  Android takes the "color=" and makes it the button background color (overriding backgroundColor: in the stylesheet).  While, iOS takes the "color=" and makes it the text color and uses the background color appropriately in the style sheet.  This makes it very difficult to have a single code set handle all buttons correctly.

Answer (score 12):

I think it is definitely better to use TouchableOpacity instead of Button tag as Button is creating styling discrepancies in Android and iOS platforms .

You can use the code below and it looks very similar to a button and it acts like one:

```
 <TouchableOpacity
         style={styles.button}
         onPress={this.onPress}
       >
         <Text> Touch Here </Text>
 </TouchableOpacity>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#DDDDDD',
    padding: 10
  }
})
```

Comment: i'm actually doing this but i still am forced to give the Text its own color... even though the TouchableOpacity has its own class with its own color. Is there even a way to inherit? Like if TouchableOpacity has color: purple.. then all text nodes under will also?

Answer (score 4):

Yes button does not respond to styles.
But alternative solution is that we can use react-native-element component.

First install the packages which is mentioned below

npm install react-native-elements
npm i react-native-linear-gradient
npm i react-native-vector-icons

And then import the packages to your code

```
    import { Button } from 'react-native-elements';
    import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';
    import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

    <Button ViewComponent={LinearGradient} // Don't forget this!
    linearGradientProps={{
    colors: ['#ffffff','blue', 'grey'],
    start: { x: 0, y: 0.5 },
    end: { x: 1, y: 0.5 },
    }} onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('First')} title="Click me"/>
```

For more info here is the link: https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/button.html

Answer (score -1):

You can make it like this

```
<Button title="Hello World!" buttonStyle={styles.btnstylehere}/>

 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 btnstylehere:{
        width: 75,
        height: 75,
        borderRadius: 0,
        backgroundColor: '#000',
        color: '#fff'

    }
})
```

Comment: This is not working for me. If it works for you, it looks to be not compatible with all versions