# Components in React-Native. How to add colour?

Tags: react-native

I want to have a button component since all my buttons will be the same size. They should, however, have different colours. Where/how can I specify the colour?

Comment: You can find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41754471/change-button-color-react-native

Comment: Does this answer your question? [change button color react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41754471/change-button-color-react-native)

Answer (score 0):

If you are building your button components on top of react-native Button you could design them to take a this color (and onPress callback) as a prop.

ButtonComponent.js (using Button from https://reactnative.dev/docs/button)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native';

function ButtonComponent(props) {
  return <Button onPress={props.onPress} title="My Button Component" color={props.color} />;
}
```

According to the docs, the color prop decides the "Color of the text (iOS), or background color of the button (Android)"